# Flutter - Call API Rest

Tags: flutter

I have 3 .dart files: The Model, the API Call and the *view*. *View* call to the service to retrieve data, like this.

Model

```
class MapData {
  String calle;
  String pais;
  String poblacion;
  String postal;
  String provincia;

  MapData({
    this.calle,
    this.pais,
    this.poblacion,
    this.postal,
    this.provincia,
  });

  factory MapData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => new MapData(

        calle: json["results"][0]['address_components'][1]["long_name"],
        pais: json["results"][0]['address_components'][5]["long_name"],
        poblacion: json["results"][0]['address_components'][2]["long_name"],
        postal: json["results"][0]['address_components'][6]["long_name"],
        provincia: json["results"][0]['address_components'][3]["long_name"],
      );
}
```

Service

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:datameter/models/mapData_model.dart';

class DatameterService {
  static Future<MapData> getMapData() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    final response = await http
        .get(
      'https://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=' +
          "43.321146" +
          ',' +
          "-3.008724" +
          '&key=KEY",
    )
        .catchError((error) {
      print(error.toString());
    });
    var responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
    if (responseJson != null) {
      final responseJson = json.decode(response.body);
      return MapData.fromJson(responseJson);
    }
    return null;
  }
}
```

Main view

```
  void initState() {
        print(DatameterService.getMapData()); //This doesn´t work
        super.initState();
      }
```

The problem: I don´t know how can i get the data.

So: What is the rigth way to get api call data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to print a future!

Maybe try this:

```
void initState() {
  DatameterService.getMapData().then((map){
   print(map);
  });
  super.initState();
 }
```

In the initstate you cannot await for future to complete but you can do something when it completes with the keyword "then".